# EXCEL : INDIRECT with LEFT Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my workbook, I have sheet called `DayWise2019`. I am trying to check if B Column text is `SBI-O` and C column first two character is `DB`. If that matching I am getting the sum of column D to another sheet 2019 `D5` cell.

Here the problem is I am unable to use left formula to check first two character in `C`

If I use below formula in 2019 `D5` cell, its calculating values correctly.

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "D" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "D" &D$3),INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "B" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "B" &D$3),"SBI-O",INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$3),"DB-BAN")
```

But as you can see, I have hardcoded "DB-BAN" above. If I replace that with a left function like below

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "D" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "D" &D$3),INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "B" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "B" &D$3),"SBI-O",INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$3),LEFT(INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$2):INDIRECT("'" & ShortCodes!$H$20 & "'!" & "C" &D$3),6))
```

Is there anyway to resolve it ?

[Sample Sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgQc2ivMWd0lg41SaYDHqGOwNgVlnQ)

Comment: Couldn't you just sumifs on `"DB*"` ?

Comment: btw, couldn't address concatenation like `...  & "'!" & "C" & ...` be shortened to `...  & "'!C" & ...` ?

Comment: @Jeeped        There are some options start with DB which I need to exclude

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand how Left is going to improve that.

Comment: @Jeeped        I messed up my question. I am looking for DayWise2019 B Column with SBI-O and C column which has first 6 letters as DB-BAN. I need to get the corresponding  D column sum and display it in 2019 sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try¹,

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\D")&D$2&":D"&D$3),
        INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\B")&D$2&":B"&D$3), "SBI-O",
        INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\C")&D$2&":C"&D$3), "DB-BAN*")
```

Using `"DB-BAN*"` as the criteria is the same as comparing the six left-most characters to `"DB-BAN"`.

---

¹ <sub>Yes, you can use different lines in the formula bar to line up important sections of a formula without detriment.</sub>

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is there anyway I can display all other cell sum which not equal to "DB-BAN*" ? ie SBI-O along with DB options not equal to "DB-BAN*"

Comment: Criteria as `"<>DB-BAN*"` should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. All working as expected. Also working on concatenate to shorten the code

Comment: I don't think it will get much shorter than above.

Comment: when I use this code with any column after Z, its not working. for example below code giving me invalid value error 
  SUMIFS(INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\AB")&D$2&":AB"&D$3),INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\Z")&D$2&":Z"&D$3), "SBI-O",INDIRECT(TEXT(ShortCodes!$H$20, "'@'!\AA")&D$2&":AA"&D$3), "DB-BAN*")

Comment: In a format mask like `"'@'!\AB"` you have to use a backslash to escape characters that would be used for other things. B is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804557/what-does-bb-or-bbbb-represent-in-an-en-us-text-function-or-custom-number-format). Just backslash the B like `"'@'!\A\B"`. In fact, I backslash everything whether I think it needs it or not.