# How can I combine text with buddhist year format date in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I tried to combine text and date in excel with this formula
=D1&" "&D2&" : "&TEXT(C2,"[$-0101041e]dd-mmm-yy")
but the problem is I couldn't get the  buddhist year with this format
I also tried 
=D1&" "&D2&" : "&TEXT(C2,"[$-0101041e]dd-mmm-bb") but it didn't work.

The buddhist year is Gregorian year + 543 such as this year is 2019 then buddhist year will be 2562

Comment: Care to share an example of what the buddhist year format looks like for those of us that don't know

Comment: @urdearboy - The Buddhist calendar is simply the one you're used to plus 543 years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804557

Comment: I was just looking this up and saw that. I'm sure just adding 543 years is a huge over simplification so i'll look into the link you shared - thanks @user11121185

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/bbbb")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=D1&" "&D2&" : "&TEXT(DATE(YEAR(C2)+543,MONTH(C2),DAY(C2)),"[$-0101041e]dd-mmm-yyyy")
```